# What were the design reasons behind Linq's extension methods not accepting true System.Predicates?

Tags: c#, linq, predicate

I noticed something when doing some programming. I decided that instead of doing something along the lines of using Predicates with Exists() and then Find() like so:

```
            Predicate<dynamic> pred = cov => cov.EmployeeId == EmployeeId;
            if (EmployeeCoverageTerminated.Exists(pred))
            {
                var foundCoverage = EmployeeCoverageTerminated.Find(pred);
            }
```

I tried to use FirstOrDefault as a replacement and tried to pass in my Predicate and realized it didn't work.

```
            //does not work
            Predicate<dynamic> pred = cov => cov.EmployeeId == EmployeeId;
            var foundCovarage = EmployeeCoverageCurrent.FirstOrDefault(pred);

             //works fine
            var foundCoverage = EmployeeCoverageCurrent.FirstOrDefault(cov => cov.EmployeeId == EmployeeId);

              //also works fine
            Func<dynamic, bool> func = cov => cov.EmployeeId == EmployeeId;
            var foundCoverage = EmployeeCoverageCurrent.FirstOrDefault(func);
```

I had to wonder, why was it designed so that it instead requires a 
`Func<T,bool>` instead of `Predicate<dynamic>` when Find() and Exists() both are fine with Predicates. I mean even the parameter input name is called *predicate*.

The only thing I can come up with is that they were implemented separately as [Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Exists](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca(v=vs.110).aspx) are part of List<> whereas [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549039(v=vs.110).aspx) is part of [Enumerable's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable(v=vs.110).aspx) Linq extension methods

I am guessing the idea is since Lambda expressions could be converted to Func<> or Predicate<> when needed and since most people used them, people would just continue to use them not realizing the new Linq APIs actually had different parameters/did not contain any overloads taking an actual [System.Predicate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz(v=vs.110).aspx)

Anyway, what was the reasoning behind this design decision?

Comment: Because the generic `List<T>` class exists since .Net 2.0 (along with `Predicate<T>`) and it had to remain backward compatible. But `Func<T>` (along with `Expression<T>`) and Linq only introduced in .Net 3.5 so the new Linq methods (like `FirstOrDefault()`, for example) were able to rely on the new `Func<T>` type with no backward-compatibility concerns.

Comment: Also, you have to distinguish between the "predicate" *term* and the `Predicate` *type*. Passing a `Func<T, bool>` to `Where()` or `FirstOrDefault()` can definitely be considered a "predicate" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic))

Comment: Worth noting probably that with `public bool f(int t) => true;` `f` will implicitly cast to either `Predicate<int>` for the old `List<T>` methods, or `Func<int, bool>` for the new LINQ extension methods.

Comment: @EdPlunkett ,  can you clarify just a bit, I cannot get that code snippet to work.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett And you want me to guess what you did that broke it? No, but [here's a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YFa1HY). Anyway, haim770 has the correct answer to why it was done this way. As we very often find with strange inconsistencies in .NET, "it seems history is to blame".

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/348151/1810205